# Finding all domains for a machine in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a web application for our group in university. I want to create a login page, where users can enter the username and password. Also, they should be able to choose a domain name (just like when you remote desktop to another machine on the system). I want to populate domain names automatically in a drop-down menu. How can i get all the domain names for a given machine in c#?

Thanks

Comment: I might very well be mistaken, but I think you can only easily get the domain of the current machine; which, in this case, would be the domain of your web server.

Comment: 99% sure the OP means the list of AD domains in the AD tree in which the server resides.

Comment: Did you think any of the answers posted merited an upvote or answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    StringCollection adDomains = this.GetDomainList();
    foreach (string strDomain in adDomains)
    {
        Response.Write("<br>" + strDomain + "</b>");
    }
}

private StringCollection GetDomainList()
{
    StringCollection domainList = new StringCollection();
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry en = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://");

        // Search for objectCategory type "Domain"
        DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher("objectCategory=Domain");
        SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();

        // Enumerate over each returned domain.
        foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
        {
            ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = rs.Properties;
            foreach( object domainName in resultPropColl["name"])
            {
                domainList.Add(domainName.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    return domainList;
}
```

[Quoted from here.](http://www.netomatix.com/ListOfDomains.aspx)